# Data Structure: Big O time cost

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

1) The time cost to add n elements to an initially empty singly linked list by 
inserting at the front of the list.

the answer seems to be one of these  O(n) or O(1). 
I think it is O(1) because 
inserting an element into empty list is just
for example  `Node element = 1;`

But I'm still not sure about this.

2)What would be the best-case time cost to find a data element in a linked list with n elements.

The answer also seems to be either O(1) or O(n).
I think it's O(n) because it has to traverse through the list to find the element.

Comment: Close voters: One can argue the question is "off topic" or "too localized", but the question is NOT: ambigious, vague, overly broad or rhetoerical, and it is pretty obvious what is the question in here. So it is NOT "not a real question". Please remember to read the close reason before voting.

Comment: +1 for giving it a try first. Many nowdays skip this step and post their question before trying to think on their own. This (your) behavior should be encouraged IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The time cost to add n elements to an initially empty singly linked list by 
inserting at the front of the list.
```

It is `O(1)` *per insertion*, but you have `n` of those - so `O(n)` at total.

> the best-case time cost to find a data element in a linked list  with
>   n elements

It is `O(1)`, because at *best case* - the searched element is the first one, so there is no need to traverse the list, after searching the first element (which is constant time) - you can halt.